# Why Google data studio csv connector works wrongly

Tags: csv, looker-studio

I have a problem with [this GDS connector](https://github.com/googledatastudio/community-connectors/tree/master/fetch-csv), when I add my csv-file, configure connector and start working with data, data appears incorrectly. Here it works okay:

[image]

But when I add another column, it goes wrong:

[image]

You can see code in GitHub repository.

I’m new to GDS connectors, I don’t know how to solve this problem. I tried another connector by Supermetrics and it works fine, but they don’t share their code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## CSV

**1) File Upload (Official CSV Connector by Google)**

- How about using the [CSV Connector by Google](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7333350)?
- Added a GIF showing the location from the [Google Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com/) page:

[image]

**2) Google Sheets (Alternative solution)**:

- There are two ways to import CSV data to Google Sheets:

  1. [Import Data Set](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/40608): Opening and saving the CSV file as a Google Sheet
  2. [`IMPORTDATA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093335): The function imports CSV data from a URL
- Added an [Editable Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZzaSNtfL2KT_8lyrhDXcz2d2JWC5DSXTTloDqkkd7T0/edit?usp=sharing) along with a GIF to demonstrate the [`IMPORTDATA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093335) function:
- [image]

**3) Fetch CSV Community Connector**:

- The [Fetch CSV Community Connector](https://github.com/googledatastudio/community-connectors/tree/master/fetch-csv) is not an Official Google connector, however it's an open source connector, so perhaps a user could have a look through provide some insights (it would be better to update the question with the relevant code). In addition, you could reach out to the authors of the connector by creating a [New Issue](https://github.com/googledatastudio/community-connectors/issues).

## Original Post: Date (Text) to Date (TODATE)

The `date` field is currently detected and formatted as a **Text** field. To ensure that the `date` field is a Google Data Studio recognised **Date** field, create the following [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) that uses the [`TODATE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7037300) function:

```
TODATE(date, "%Y-%m-%d", "%Y%m%d")
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/b795a3b4-5fcb-4fc9-9318-d46fc2ed04e3) as well as a GIF to elaborate:

[image]